# How to connect Power BI Desktop to ssrs report server

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, powerbi

I am using Report Builder 3.0 in order to connect to SSRS report server http://mosaic.catex.com/reportserver.
Is there a way to use Power BI to connect to SSRS report server instead?

[image]
[image]
Thanks

Comment: What do you want to accomplish by connecting Power BI to the SSRS report server? Power BI reports aren't supported in SSRS, though there is a technical preview for the next version of SQL Server (not yet released):  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlrsteamblog/2017/01/18/getting-started-with-the-technical-preview-of-power-bi-reports-in-sql-server-reporting-services/

Comment: I need to build dashboards, however i don't want my data source to be excel files extracted from SSRS report server (i use report builder to built my reports and extract it into excel files)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt598750.aspx . Last time I tried it, it was a giant pain but then again that was during sql 2016 testing phase.

Comment: So you want to use an SSRS report as a data source? I'm not sure that's possible at the moment but it would be simpler to recreate the query that you use in SSRS and use that as a dataset in Power BI. If you are doing calculations within your report these can be recreated using Power BI desktop as calculated members, you can then publish these to Power BI web version. Last time I checked you could not create calculated members in the web version.

Answer (score 2):

Answering the question that was originally asked: there's no way to connect Power BI Desktop to SSRS Report Server. Power BI Report Server is another matter, but your question predates its release so that is very unlikely to be what you're asking about.

Power BI Desktop (which I presume you mean when you say *Power BI*) and Report Builder (pictured in your question) are different tools used to build different types of reports. There's no overlap between them and they're not interchangeable.

There's also no way to use an SSRS report as a data source in Power BI (as *Alan* mentions), though I wouldn't recommend doing this even if it were possible. In SSRS 2016, there is a way to pin SSRS report elements to a Power BI dashboard (as *Snowlockk* mentions), but I'm not sure that's what you meant by "dashboard" in your comment. The functionality is somewhat limited too (since you need to be running SSRS 2016, and you can only pin chart/gauge/map/picture elements).

When asking *if* something can be done, it's always helpful to say exactly what you're trying to accomplish just in case it can't be done the way you're asking about, but it can be done another way.